# Scraped data is printed in console but not in csv-file

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, export-to-csv

### Hi everyone, big fan over here of SO

so I'm building a crawler, and it prints the data fine to the console, and even creates the wanted csv-file - but the file is empty. There is clearly a miscommunication between the data and the output file but I cannot see my mistakes.
I'd it already checked with PyCharm, but that didn't bring up anything :( .

I am including my code (just changed the website I'm scraping from) and would be ever so grateful to everyone who offers guidance!

---

`from random import randint
from typing import List
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

session = requests.Session()

path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/me/Desktop/chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

headers = {"user-agent": "Chrome/67.0.3396.87"}

dns = 'https://www.example.com/'
url = dns + 'specific-profile-page/'


def r_sleep(sleep=None, mylog=None):
    length: float = float(randint(2000, 10000)) / 1000
    mylog("Safety Random Sleep has started for {0} sec".format(length))
    sleep(length)
    mylog("Safety Random Sleep is over")


browser.get(url)
elements = browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Profile')
links = []

class CrawledDoctor:
      def __init__(self, title, special, partner, street, area, phone, web):

        self.title = title
        self.special = special
        self.partner = partner
        self.street = street
        self.area = area
        self.phone = phone
        self.web = web


class DoctorFetcher:
    def fetch(self):
        doctors: List[CrawledDoctor] = []
        while url != "":
            print("Current page ", url)
            r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


            print(r.status_code)
            if r.status_code != 200:
                print('request returns invalid status code')

            for i in range(len(elements)):
                links.append(elements[i].get_attribute('href'))

            for link in links:
                print('navigating to: ' + link)
                new_page = browser.get(link)

                # do stuff within that page here...
                if new_page is None:
                    print("Start scraping ...")
                soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml', exclude_encodings=["ISO-8859-7"])

                for info in soup.select('#profil_name_adresse'):
                    try:
                        title = info.select_one('h1').text
                        print(title)
                        special = info.select_one('p.grau').text
                        print(special)
                        try:
                            partner = info.find('a.link-black').attrs[
                                'href'].text  
                            print(partner)
                        except AttributeError:  
                            partner = print('no partner')
                        street = info.find('p', {'class': 'grau'}).next_sibling.contents[0]
                        print(street)
                        area = info.find('p', {'class': 'grau'}).next_sibling.contents[2]
                        print(area)
                        phone = info.find('p', {'class': 'grau'}).next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.contents[0]
                        print(phone)
                        web = info.find('p', {'class': 'grau'}).next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.a.text
                        print(web)
                    except AttributeError:
                        print("Keine Angabe")
                    crawled = CrawledDoctor(title, special, partner, street, area, phone, web)
                    doctors.append(crawled)
                    browser.back()

        return doctors



import csv

fetcher = DoctorFetcher()

with open('myfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    doctorwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for doctor in fetcher.fetch:
        doctorwriter.writerow(
            [doctor.title, doctor.special, doctor.partner, doctor.street, doctor.area, doctor.phone, doctor.web])
<code>
 -`

Comment: I think you miss brackets when you call `fetcher.fetch()`.

Comment: Sadly adding those brackets did not fix it, but thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Take your code and strip out all of the Selenium related stuff... just mock some data and write it to the CSV file... now does it work? Try things like `print(doctor.title)`, etc... does that work? You really need to do some more debugging and strip the code down to a [mcve] on your own. You'll likely find the issue while doing that.